# Generate a sorted map in Rust

Tags: iterator, rust, b-tree

I am looking for a way to generate a sorted map, having the keys sorted by multiple values.

Something like this:

```
let mut f = File::open("storing_data_like_a_pro.csv")?;
let mut buffer = String::new();
f.read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;
let sorted_cache_map: BTreeMap<String, FancyParsedData> = buffer.lines()
   .map(|line| FancyParsedData::new(line)
   .map(|data| (data.key, data))
   // .sortBy(|key, value| value.foo, ASCENDING)
   // .thenSortBy(|key, value| value.bar, DESCENDING)...
   .collect();
```

When I know the key I would get a snappy response. If I would search like one or multiple values, I want them to be ordered (useful for pagination).

Comment: I think you need to make a wrapper type that adds an `Ord` overload that matches what you want. Sorting by `x` then `y` means sorting by the tuple `(x, y)`.